# Amazon Simple Queue Service in Localhost

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, apache2, localhost, amazon-sqs

It is possible to use the AWS SQS (php) in mac(apache2 server).

I got the below error when try locally,
Uncaught exception 'cURL_Exception' with message 'cURL resource: Resource id #44; cURL error: Could not resolve host: https (cURL error code 6). See http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html for an explanation of error codes.https://' in...

Answer (score -2):

Yes, its definitely possible to use SQS from localhost - I do it all the time.

Comment: Can you give me guidelines, i have a valid key & secret key also.

Comment: But i got the error.... Uncaught exception 'cURL_Exception' with message 'cURL resource: Resource id #44; cURL error: Could not resolve host: https (cURL error code 6)

Comment: But the problem in local setup.

Comment: can you give your code to check ? (remove access key / secret key before posting  E.J. is correct, you can call SQS API from everywhere.  This is most probably a network configuration issue

Comment: @SébastienStormacq - thank you. I am adding SQS in my application. Accessing SQS using REST API is handy.   For example we can change endpoint for test and production.